# undefined offset PHP, not sure what it does

Tags: php, session

I have the following error in PHP error.log

> [Tue Dec 19 12:08:22.887574 2017] [:error] [pid 32196] [client xx.xx.xx.x:20560] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 8 in /var/www/html/page.php on line 55, referer: view.php?1x=8

and the php code that i think causes this is:

```
$i = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? $_SESSION['i'] : 0;
// echo $_SESSION['websites'][$i];
$website = explode(";", $_SESSION['websites'][$i]);
// echo $website[0];
$i++;
$_SESSION['i'] = $i;
```

I dont really know what `$i = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? $_SESSION['i'] : 0;` does

thank you

```
session_start();
$i = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? $_SESSION['i'] : 0;
if ($_SESSION['i'] < $sesioni1x) {  
    // echo $_SESSION['websites'][$i];
    $website = explode(";", $_SESSION['websites'][$i]);
    // echo $website[0];
    $i++;
    $_SESSION['i'] = $i;
        header("Location: $website[0]"); //redirect
        die();
        // echo $website[0];
        // echo $sesioni1x;
        // echo $website[0]." Frame-URL<br>";
        // $_SESSION['actual_website'] = $website[0];
}           
if ($_SESSION['i'] == $sesioni1x) {
    $handle = fopen($list1x, "a"); //open file to append content to csv file
    fputcsv($handle, $_SESSION['addwebsite'], ";"); //insert line in opened file
    fclose($handle); //close file
    header("Location: index.php"); //redirect
    die(); 
    // echo "session = var";
    }
```

this is the full code where i get this warning, i must say that script is doing his job, but i want to get rid of the error

the `$_SESSION['i']` in the source is 0

Comment: `$i` checks for if session is already set or not and if `$_SESSION['i']` is already set then assign its value to `$i` else assigns `0`

Comment: Which is line 55?

Answer (score 5):

this is ternary called ternary operator. Basically it is a simple if/else.

```
$i = (isset($_SESSION['i']) ? $_SESSION['i'] : 0);
```

To help you understand it's this code in 1 line

```
if(isset($_SESSION['i'])){
    $i=$_SESSION['i'];
}
else{
    $i=0;
}
```

Comment: ty, got it, i googled for operators, but never heard of ternary
thank you one more time

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? $_SESSION['i'] : 0;
```

The above code is just an if/else nothing else
this will check for the `$_SESSION['i']` is it is set then assign it's value to `$i` otherwise it assigns `0` to `$i` variable.

Now looking to your problem, it looks like your `$_SESSION['i']` is already set and its value is `8` so $i = 8,

Now, `$website = explode(";", $_SESSION['websites'][$i]);` this like is checking for your `$_SESSION['website']` array and trying to find `8th` element from the array which has not been set so it gives an error its undefined.

Comment: Index=8 => 9th element

Comment: yeah index is 8 and element is 9th

Answer (score 1):

(e) ? r1 : r2 is a conditional statement.
If the expression e is true the value is r1, if e is false the value is r2. So

```
$i = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? $_SESSION['i'] : 0;
```

means "i is $_SESSION['i'], if $_SESSION['i'] is set, otherwise it is 0".